# Return a value that indicate the column has multiple values

Tags: sql, sqlite

How to write SQL query to count column that have same value and return a value that indicate the column has multiple values. See example below.

**My attempt:**

```
SELECT ID, 'X' AS TYPE 
    FROM SAMPLE_TABLE 
    WHERE TYPE = 'C'
    GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) > 1 
    UNION 
    SELECT * FROM SAMPLE_TABLE  
    GROUP BY ID HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

**Sample**

```
+-----------+
| ID | TYPE |
+-----------+
|101 |  C   |
|102 |  A   |
|102 |  B   |
|103 |  A   |
|104 |  B   |
|104 |  C   |
|105 |  A   |
|105 |  C   |
+-----------+
```

**My Result:**

```
+-----------+
| ID | TYPE |
+-----------+
|101 |  C   |
|103 |  A   |
+-----------+
```

**Expected:**

```
+-----------+
| ID | TYPE |
+-----------+
|101 |  C   |
|104 |  X   |
|105 |  X   |
+-----------+
```

Comment: What happened to rows 102 and 103 in your results?

Comment: Query did not return result for 102 and 103 returned 'A'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select id,
       case when sum(type <> 'C') then 'X' else 'C' end type
from tablename
group by id
having sum(type = 'C') > 0
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pxJf33eWKMnAoEd4qJAeAR/0).
Results:

```
| ID  | type |
| --- | ---- |
| 101 | C    |
| 104 | X    |
| 105 | X    |
```

Comment: What if we want to search by 'B' or 'C' so we can get 101:C, 102:X, 104:X and 105:X

Comment: Check this: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pxJf33eWKMnAoEd4qJAeAR/1

Answer (score 0):

You can use aggregation and `case`:

```
select id,
       (case when min(type) = max(type) then min(type) else 'X' end) as type
from t
group by id;
```

Comment: I want to return the IDs that have 'C' and if the ID has 'C' and another type, return as 'X', which 'X' indicates this ID has 'C' and another type.

Comment: @PLOW . . . If the types are the same on all rows for an `id`, then it returns the type.  Otherwise, it returns `'X'`.  That is how I interpret the question.